# Multibyte Character Exploits JSP/PostgreSQL

Tags: web-application, xss, java

I am trying to secure a web application, written in Java/JSP and running on PostgreSQL, against SQL injection. I ran into this very interesting [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9908/multibyte-character-exploits-php-mysql), which refers to PHP and MySQL. Is there any resource on multibyte SQL injection against JSP/PostgreSQL? In particular, is `PreparedStatement` sufficient to protect the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multibyte based SQL Injection is only an issue if [mysql's encoding has  been set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) to GBK.  Your client and all of your tables should probably be in UTF-8 for compatibility or Latin1(seems to be the default in the USA). Multibyte character exploits are not a problem with these two encoding types.